# Ionic Storage value will not display on HTML until page is reloaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, events, ionic-storage

Ionic Storage values aren't displaying on HTML until page gets reloaded.
I looked into some other people who had the same problems but the solutions I found either don't work or don't work anymore due to Ionic version changes. An example would be the Event system in Ionic.

HTML:
displays Name, and two dates

```
<ion-list>
    <div *ngFor="let data of data2">

    <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-label text-left>
          Fruit Name:
        </ion-label>
        <ion-label text-right>
          {{data.FruitName}}
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label text-left>
        Install Date:
      </ion-label>
      <ion-label text-right>
        {{data.installTime}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label text-left>
        Remove Date:
      </ion-label>
      <ion-label text-right>
        {{data.removeTime}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>


    </div>

</ion-list>
```

.TS

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

 //My Variables

 data2;
 _idx;

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private storage: Storage,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  params => {

      /*Update Variables here*/

      this._idx = Temperature.__idx;
      this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        this.storage.get(this._idx).then(data=>{
          //if data exists
          if(data)
            {
             console.log("data read");
             this.data2 = data;
             console.log(data);
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("data is empty");
              this.data2 = [];
            }
        });
      });
  });
}

}
```

When I load the routing page for the first time

[image]

When I change routing page then go back to the original.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .ts file do this,

```
import {
    ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';
import {
    Storage
} from '@ionic/storage';
import {
    ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';


export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    //My Variables
    routeParams;
    data2;
    _idx;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private storage: Storage,
        private changeRef: ChangeDectetorRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routePrams = this.route.params.subscribe(params => /** ... do whatever you need to do in here that involves params **/);

        this._idx = Temperature.__idx;                                                    
        this.storage.get(this._idx).then(data=>{
          //if data exists
          if(data)
            {
             console.log("data read");
             this.data2 = data;
             console.log(data);
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("data is empty");
              this.data2 = [];
            }
            this.changeRef.detectChanges();
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeParams.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

**Explanation:** I don't know why you're using `storage.ready()` it is not needed. I don't know why you're making a storage call inside an observable that is never used in the storage call; separate them (unless you are using the param variable). You need to unsubscribe from every subscription you make; do so otherwise you risk [client side memory leaks](https://www.twilio.com/blog/prevent-memory-leaks-angular-observable-ngondestroy).

In your template .html do this,

```
<ion-list *ngIf="data2">
    <div *ngFor="let data of data2">

        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label text-left>
                Fruit Name:
            </ion-label>
            <ion-label text-right>
                {{data.FruitName}}
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label text-left>
                Install Date:
            </ion-label>
            <ion-label text-right>
                {{data.installTime}}
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label text-left>
                Remove Date:
            </ion-label>
            <ion-label text-right>
                {{data.removeTime}}
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>


    </div>

</ion-list>
```

**Explanation:** Since your storage result is a promise-like object you need to wait for it to resolve. You can do that by doing a template check on the status of the variable `data2` that you're trying to set via storage call. It is initially unset but after the storage call resolves it is set. This resolution might happen outside of the angular lifecycle hooks, hence why you're seeing the page initially blank and then when you reload it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this also has the same results where the page does not load. The data loads eventually when I sit on the page which I can view on the inspector console (f12). But the HTML page does not change even with the *ngIf="data2" after the data2 has been set.

Comment: So the data loads without you leaving the page and coming back, it just comes after awhile?

Comment: Yeah, in the ngOnInit() I have console.log(data); which shows the data and all the values it contains in the console. Even though data2 is set with values, the HTML page doesn't display this unless I change routing page then come back.

Comment: @win4win have you tried using angular change dectector reference https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef. It allows you to force angular to check your component for changes in data and update the template. I have edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: IT WORKED, https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/ ChangeDectors was just what I needed! Thanks!!